# How do I add a comment to an answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I looked all over the help and FAQ and couldn't find how to do a basic thing like respond to a Stack Overflow answer. I don't want to answer the question, I simply want to add a comment to an existing answer that someone posted to the question.

Comment: You need a certain amount of reputation before you can do that, I believe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment  50 reputation.  So you need 34 more.

Answer (score 2):

You can't comment on answers until you have at least 50 reputation points: see [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it? | Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

There will be a grey 'reply' button that looks like text underneath this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need 50+ points to  Leave comments.Though you can leave comments on your own questions right from the get go.